# Most basic AngularJS binding not working / bower not installing

Tags: angularjs, binding

I am working through [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) and can't even seem to get past the most basic Angular feature of evaluating a binding like `{{ 1 + 2 }}`

The page still displays the code:

```
<p>1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
```

as:

```
1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}
```

When I run `node --version` I get: v5.7.0

How can I debug this type of problem?

--

Full code of index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

  <p>1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

--

It seems due to this problem: the directory and files in "bower_components" have not downloaded when running "npm install". This is the error log I got when running this command:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/angular-phonecat$ npm install
angular-phonecat@0.0.0 /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat
└─┬ karma@0.12.37
  ├─┬ http-proxy@0.10.4
  │ └── optimist@0.6.1
  └── optimist@0.6.1

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! path ../semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/angular-phonecat$
```

npm-debug.log:

```
...
/protractor/node_modules/optimist
    1110 silly finalize /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q
    1111 silly finalize /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/saucelabs
    1112 silly finalize /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor
    1113 silly doSerial build 10
    1114 silly build semver@5.0.3
    1115 info linkStuff semver@5.0.3
    1116 silly linkStuff semver@5.0.3 has /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules as its parent node_modules
    1117 verbose linkBins semver@5.0.3
    1118 verbose link bins [ { semver: './bin/semver' },
    1118 verbose link bins   '/home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin',
    1118 verbose link bins   false ]
    1119 verbose linkMans semver@5.0.3
    1120 silly gentlyRm /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin/semver is being purged
    1121 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin/semver
    1122 verbose unlock done using /home/vagrant/.npm/_locks/staging-4adac74316f20e6c.lock for /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/.staging
    1123 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
    1124 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
    1125 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
    1126 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
    1127 silly install printInstalled
    1128 warn optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
    1129 warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9
    1130 verbose stack Error: EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin/semver'
    1130 verbose stack     at Error (native)
    1131 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat
    1132 error Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
    1133 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
    1134 error node v5.7.0
    1135 error npm  v3.6.0
    1136 error path ../semver/bin/semver
    1137 error code EPROTO
    1138 error errno -71
    1139 error syscall symlink
    1140 error EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/angular-phonecat/node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/.bin/semver'
    1141 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
    1141 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
    1142 verbose exit [ -71, true ]
```

Comment: No, it is in the code: "<html lang="en" ng-app>"

Answer (score 0):

Does the Console window in the F12 developer tools report any errors?
Also,  you complain about bower,  is the angularjs file present in the directory: bower_components/angular/angular.js

Comment: F12 console says that a css file is missing, which I suspect belongs into the folder bower_components. In fact, the entire bower_components folder in my project directory is missing. when i run the npm install command (which as i understand installs various libraries and APIs) i get errors (see above). working with these frameworks is really utterly frustrating ...

Comment: If it's a new project use bower install angular

Comment: If it's a downloaded project,  use bower update and it should use their bower. Json  file and download the dependencies